# Image size issue using Angularjs and ionic

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, image

I'm trying to make that 1 image take 50% height and 100% width of the screen and the second picture to the same.

Look at the picture below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwmRP.jpg

Comment: are we supposed to guess what your html and css looks like?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish this using css.

```
body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
}
img{
    width: 100%
    height: 50%
}
```

Note that, for some reason, you have to set the body to 100% width and height